# Group by Help - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

How would I implement a group by to this?

Tried just grouping by everything in the select and it doesn't appear to work.

```
 SELECT SL.ORDER_NO,
   SL.HANDLING_UNIT_ID,
   HUS.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT,
   SL.OBJVERSION,
         ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_API.GET_PERIOD_DESCRIPTION(SITE_API.GET_COMPANY(SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID)),
                                                                                                    ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_API.GET_CURR_ACC_YEAR(SITE_API.GET_COMPANY(SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID))),
                                                                                                    ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_API.GET_CURR_ACC_PERIOD(SITE_API.GET_COMPANY(SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID)))) ACC_DESC,
         HUS.WIDTH,
         HUS.HEIGHT,
         HUS.DEPTH,
         SL.QUANTITY * IFSAPP.HANDLING_UNIT_API.GET_TARE_WEIGHT(HUS.HANDLING_UNIT_ID, HUS.UOM_FOR_WEIGHT) TOTAL_WEIGHT_KGS,
         HUS.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_ID CASE_NOS,
         HUS.WIDTH * HUS.HEIGHT * HUS.DEPTH DIMENSIONS,
         HUS.WIDTH * HUS.HEIGHT * HUS.DEPTH * 3 / 1000000 TOTAL_CUBE_BOX
    FROM   SHIPMENT_LINE_HANDL_UNIT SL
    JOIN   HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT_CFV HUS
    ON     HUS.SHIPMENT_ID = SL.SHIPMENT_ID
   JOIN   SHIPMENT S
   ON     S.SHIPMENT_ID = SL.SHIPMENT_ID
   JOIN   CUSTOMER_ORDER CO
   ON     CO.ORDER_NO = S.ORDER_NO
   WHERE  SHIPMENT_API.GET_STATE(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID) = 'Completed'
         AND SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID) = '1314'
   AND SL.HANDLING_UNIT_ID = HUS.HANDLING_UNIT_ID
   AND S.SHIP_VIA_CODE = 'SEA'
   AND CO.REGION_CODE = 'AM'
```

Expected data:

```
Shiptrain7       1  102 102 111x93x106  RPL111x93x106   93     111   106      3.28


Shiptrain7       1  57  57  111x93x106  RPL111x93x106   93     111   106      3.28


Shiptrain8      1   150 150 111x93x106  RPL111x93x106   93     111   106      3.28

Shiptrain8      1   2   2   35x26x33        RPL35x26x33 26     35      33        3.28
```

[image: Current result]

There is just one of each case, the handling unit id is associated to each case. Its bringing the actual ID rather than amount of each case which is 1. Also, this is being used in a crystal report so ignore the fields which arent needed.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: could you please provide your sample data and expected output in table format, as we don't know what is your sample data  - it's tough to identify your expected output

Comment: @fa06 Added to question

Comment: what is your current result from the above query @mfgn

Comment: @fa06 I'm using the group by for the first column which is essentially a count per unique case

Comment: It would be great if you show your current query result in question

Comment: @fa06 Sorry, my data is exactly like that besides, the first column as of now its bringing back the ACTUAL values of the handling units, where as i want the number of handling units per case, so 1, 1, 1, 1

Comment: It is very difficult for us to be able to help you, based on the information you have provided. We don't know your tables, data, or requirements, so we have to go from what you tell us, which isn't much. For example, you say you want "the number of handling units per case". What's a handling unit? What's a case? We don't really care about anything other than "this is the data I have, and these are the results I want to get from that, and the logic is <this>" Please update your question to include the output of your current query and what you want it to be, along with how to derive it.

Comment: @Boneist Updated, I've gave as much info as i can.

Comment: Hi @mfgn, can you please share the desc for each of the table involved in your query? or at least the desc of table with handling units values data.

Comment: @RohitDodle Hi, Essentially its a shipment table, has details of shipments. The first column just needs to be the quantity instead of bringing the actual values of the units. I assumed a group by could fix this.I want the number of the ID's so 1 of each ID. Rather than the actual values

Comment: @mfgn, if you did your grouping correctly, all you need is probably just a count(column_name) in place of column_name. Please see if it works and let me know. Also, is it first column or the second? Order No or Handling Unit?

Comment: @RohitDodle Please can you write out the code and ill copy it in? and second column, so how would i go about doing a COUNT

Comment: Never mind. APCs answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to GROUP BY everything in the projection except the `handling_unit_id`, which you just want to count. You could alter the existing query, but you have a large number of derived columns which will make the GROUP BY clause complicated and brittle.

So you should wrap the existing query in another query which you can use for aggregation. Note that you must give an alias to each column in the query.

```
select order_no
       , count(handling_unit_id) as no_of_units
       , manual_gross_weight
       , objversion
       ,  acct_period_description
        ,  acct_period
       , acc_desc
       , width
       , height
       , depth
       , total_weight_kgs
       , case_nos
       , dimensions
        , total_cube_box
from (
     SELECT SL.ORDER_NO,
       SL.HANDLING_UNIT_ID,
       HUS.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT,
       SL.OBJVERSION,
       ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_API.GET_PERIOD_DESCRIPTION(SITE_API.GET_COMPANY(SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID)) as  acct_period_description,
       ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_API.GET_CURR_ACC_YEAR(SITE_API.GET_COMPANY(SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID))) as acct_period,
       ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_API.GET_CURR_ACC_PERIOD(SITE_API.GET_COMPANY(SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID)))) ACC_DESC,
             HUS.WIDTH,
             HUS.HEIGHT,
             HUS.DEPTH,
             SL.QUANTITY * IFSAPP.HANDLING_UNIT_API.GET_TARE_WEIGHT(HUS.HANDLING_UNIT_ID, HUS.UOM_FOR_WEIGHT) TOTAL_WEIGHT_KGS,
             HUS.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_ID CASE_NOS,
             HUS.WIDTH * HUS.HEIGHT * HUS.DEPTH DIMENSIONS,
             HUS.WIDTH * HUS.HEIGHT * HUS.DEPTH * 3 / 1000000 TOTAL_CUBE_BOX
        FROM   SHIPMENT_LINE_HANDL_UNIT SL
        JOIN   HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT_CFV HUS
        ON     HUS.SHIPMENT_ID = SL.SHIPMENT_ID
       JOIN   SHIPMENT S
       ON     S.SHIPMENT_ID = SL.SHIPMENT_ID
       JOIN   CUSTOMER_ORDER CO
       ON     CO.ORDER_NO = S.ORDER_NO
       WHERE  SHIPMENT_API.GET_STATE(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID) = 'Completed'
             AND SHIPMENT_API.GET_CONTRACT(HUS.SHIPMENT_ID) = '1314'
       AND SL.HANDLING_UNIT_ID = HUS.HANDLING_UNIT_ID
       AND S.SHIP_VIA_CODE = 'SEA'
       AND CO.REGION_CODE = 'AM'
) 
group by order_no
       , manual_gross_weight
       , objversion
       ,  acct_period_description
        ,  acct_period
       , acc_desc
       , width
       , height
       , depth
       , total_weight_kgs
       , case_nos
       , dimensions
        , total_cube_box
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I had aliases on my group by. Thanks again